# Wine on Cygwin windows compilation issue

Tags: cygwin, wine

I have installed Cygwin (32-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 and inside Cygwin I am trying to compile Wine 1.7.5 (32-bit). The entire compiling went smooth with the command:

`./configure  --without-x --without-freetype --disable-tests CFLAGS=-fgnu89-inline`

Then I was able to do "make" & "make install".

Now when I try to run winecfg i am getting the following error:

> -bash: ./winecfg: Accessing a corrupted shared library

and when I try to run wine then it can't even find it even though its defined in the $PATH.

`-bash: wine: command not found`

I am a Windows guy, so I am stumped with this issue. Please can someone assist me?

The reason I am running Wine inside Cygwin is due to the fact that I have a customer's application that does not run on a Windows Server OS. It's a 32-bit app and can run on 64-bit OS like Windows 10 or Windows 7 or even Windows 2008 Server. But i cannot run in Windows Server 2012 R2/2016. So I am trying to leverage Wine to do that as I tested with BoxedWine and it can run it. But i dont want to use BoxedWine due to various other issues that i encountered.

Comment: Please show us the result of `uname -m`. I.e., are you running a 64-bit or 32-bit version of cygwin? Output from `uname -a` might be helpful as well.

Comment: $ uname -m
i686       What i did is recompiled with Wine 3.1 and now atleast i dont see the -bash: ./winecfg: Accessing a corrupted shared library error but running winecfg is not showing anything on console. Also running wine continues to give -bash: wine: command not found error

Comment: Could you run `ldd winecfg` to try to see what is wrong there. The phrasing looks wrong for a windows error.

Comment: Unable to put the output in comments section, so added as answer below.

Comment: Check Event Viewer or run sxstrace. This message can have numerous causes. Despite its wording, it isn't always necessarily caused by a problem with a DLL. If you have bad XML in your EXE's manifest it can cause this message too

Answer (score 0):

```
    ldd winecfg
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x76ef0000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x74e20000)
    KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x767e0000)
    advapi32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/advapi32.dll (0x76da0000)
    comdlg32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/comdlg32.dll (0x76c10000)
    gdi32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/gdi32.dll (0x768c0000)
    ole32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ole32.dll (0x74b70000)
    shell32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/shell32.dll (0x74f60000)
    shlwapi.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/shlwapi.dll (0x76750000)
    user32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/user32.dll (0x76280000)
    uxtheme.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/uxtheme.dll (0x6fde0000)
    winmm.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/winmm.dll (0x6f610000)
    libwine.dll => /usr/local/lib/libwine.dll (0x713c0000)
    cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
    msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/msvcrt.dll (0x74aa0000)
    sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/sechost.dll (0x76bc0000)
    RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/RPCRT4.dll (0x76a80000)
    combase.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/combase.dll (0x765a0000)
    WINMMBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/WINMMBASE.dll (0x6f570000)
    SspiCli.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/SspiCli.dll (0x76d40000)
    cfgmgr32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/cfgmgr32.dll (0x767a0000)
    DEVOBJ.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/DEVOBJ.dll (0x736a0000)
```